# AWS Opsworks 11 does not let me add Ubuntu 14.04 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, opsworks

I am already using AWS Opsworks 11 which shows Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in the OS dropdown list.
I already have running instances in layers (Ubuntu 14.04), but when I try to add new instances then it throws me an error:

`ServiceError: Os: is not supported in this region, Root Device Type: must be included in .`

Did AWS Opsworks 11 dropped support for Ubuntu 14.04?
If yes then why the OS is still in the list?

PS. I can add Amazon linux AMI instances in that stack.

Comment: Happens for me as well. Did not happen yesterday! AWS dropped support for something, definitely.

Comment: I had various issues using the Chef 11 stacks starting about 6-8 months ago. I think they're definitely trying to force it out of their systems. If I were you, I'd look at migrating to a Chef 12 stack sooner rather than later before your entire stack stops working inexplicably.

Comment: It seems to be sure now that they are dropping the support for it. But this is strange that they did not mention it anywhere. If anyone can find a link like an announcement or something in documentation regarding this, I'll be pleased to have that one.

Comment: I've not see any official announcements, or anything in the documentation that might suggest that they're phasing it out, but the way it seems to be deteriorating within the last 12 months suggests that at least someone within the Opsworks team wants it gone. When I discovered I could no longer scale up/down/reboot my Chef 11 stack without errors, I made the decision to upgrade it to Chef 12 sooner rather than later. I'd strongly suggest you look into doing the same.

Comment: Correct. I'm also working to upgrade on Chef 12.